# How do I make a sort of INDEX MATCH with condition in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to search IF the value of `MONDAY`(row) and 1(column) equals T.
If not, it checks the one below it until the value equals to T.

However, when I use normal index match, it only returns the value `0` of the first `MONDAY-1 (B2)` instead of the second `MONDAY-1 (B3)`.

| DAY | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | Tiet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MONDAY |  | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | EPN1095 43 |
| MONDAY | T |  |  |  |  |  | T | T | T |  |  |  | MAT1093 43 |
| TUESDAY |  |  | T | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  | PHI1006 43 |
| TUESDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T |  | INT1007 43 |
| TUESDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T | T | PHI1006 43 |
| WEDNESDAY | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | MAT1041 43 |
| WEDNESDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T |  |  |  |  | INT1008 43 |
| WEDNESDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T | T | MAT1093 43 |
| THURSDAY | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | INT1007 43 |
| THURSDAY |  |  |  | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  | INT1008 43 |
| SATURDAY |  |  |  | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  | INT1008 43 |
| SATURDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T | T | MAT1041 43 |
| WEDNESDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T | T | INT1008 43 |
| THURSDAY | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | INT1008 43 |
| THURSDAY |  |  |  | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  | INT1007 43 |
| SATURDAY | T | T | T |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | MAT1093 43 |
| SATURDAY |  |  |  |  |  |  | T | T | T |  |  |  | MAT1041 43 |

Comment: It will be great if you can share the screenshot of expected output as well as the formula you have worked on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on cell `Q2` (I am not sure about your question unless you provide a sample output), if you want to calculate of the `T` values for `MONDAY`.

```
=IF(P2="","",SUM(--(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FILTER(B2:M18,A2:A18=P2),{"T"})))))
```

**Note**: If you want to search *only* for the Column 1 (that is what you have in your question), then you can use the same above formula, but just reducing the range to just the first column (`B2:B18`), but the logic remains the same:

```
=IF(P2="","",SUM(--(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FILTER(B2:B18,A2:A18=P2),{"T"})))))
```

If you want to search for `T` values for `MONDAY` `VLOOKUP` or `XLOOKUP` is a good option, because it stops at the first match if not it continues. You can use this:

```
=LET(search, 
 XLOOKUP(A2:A18&B2:B18,P2&B2:B18,B2:B18, ""), 
 IF(search=0,"", search))
```

**Note**: We concatenate the first two columns to find only for `MONDAY` and `T`. It returns an array with empty values except at the position the `T` was found and returns `T`.

Sample output for counting all `T`s for `MONDAY`:

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

You cannot use `COUNTIF`, because all the input ranges must have the same shape (rows and columns):

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:M18,"T",A2:A18,P2) -> #VALUE!
```

You cannot use `FILTER` as input range of `COUNTIF`, that is why I use `XMATCH`.

```
SUM(--(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FILTER(B2:M18,A2:A18=P2),{"T"}))))
```

Filter the range by `MONDAY` (`P2`), it will return a `2x12` array with `T` and ceros. We use `XMATCH` to identify where we have  a `T`. In cells `T` is not found `#N/A` otherwise returns `1`. We convert the result to `TRUE/FALSE` with `ISNUMBER` and then via `--` operator transform it to `1/0` values. Then wherever we have `1` there was a `T`, so `SUM` the resulting range gives the total of `T`s for `MONDAY`.

The `IF` at the beginning is just to allow expanding the formula down.